# PHP encoding issue when using http_request2

Tags: php, encoding, httprequest

I'm trying to send a request using `HTTP_REQUEST2` package to a website.

I have a try catch statement as following:

```
try {
        return $this->_HttpObject->send();//->getBody();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {

        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
```

The message looks like this:

> Unable to connect to tcp://website.com:80. Error: þþðéñéåï çéáåø ðëùì
>   îàçø ùäöã äîçåáø ìà äâéá ëøàåé ìàçø ú÷åôú æîï, àå ùéöéøú äçéáåø ðëùìä
>   îàçø ùúâåáú äîçùá äîàøç äîçåáø ðëùìä. error

I'm not sure if the error looks as it is because of php.ini encoding issues or because of the website returning this in gibrish.

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, "unable to connect to **tcp://website.com:80**" Configure your domain name in the config file..

Comment: common....i purposely changed the domain name....that isn't my problem - the problem is the encoding of the Exception message

Comment: Ow im sorry did u read this? http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.intro.php

Comment: yes i have (i know it by heart :) i believe it to be a PHP issue but i'm not sure.